# Combobox update after userform closes

Tags: vba, excel

I have problem with a `UserForm` update.

When I start the `Uform1` I fill a `ComboBox1` with a list of users of a `Sheet("User")`.
If the user is not registred u must press the button `Add user` in the `Uform1`.
When `Add user` button is pressed, `Uform2` appear (`Uform2` is in charge of registering user)

Ok my problem is when I finish with `Uform2` and I get focus back in `Uform1` the `Combobox1` doesn't show the new user. How can I do this?

Comment: If you update the sheet using the `Uform2`, then you'll have to call the sub that initialize the value of the `ComboBox1` from `Uform1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure how you initialize the `ComboBox1` value but below set up seem to work.

**UserForm1 Code:**

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click() ' Add User Button
    Me.Hide
    UserForm2.Show
End Sub
```

---

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate() ' Populate ComboBox1
    With Sheet1
        Dim lr As Long
        lr = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Me.ComboBox1.List = Application.Transpose(.Range("A1:A" & lr))
    End With
    Debug.Print "Activated"
End Sub
```

**UserForm2 Code:**

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click() ' Register Button
    With Sheet1
        Dim lr As Long
        lr = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        .Range("A" & lr + 1) = Me.TextBox1
    End With
    Me.Hide
    UserForm1.Show
End Sub
```

The key is to use `UserForm_Activate` event to fire re-populating the `ComboBox1`.